# nginx and socket.io workaround

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io, reverse-proxy

Right now, it is hard to work around most reverse proxies (nginx, HAproxy) when dealing with web sockets. I was thinking that it might be possible to do something like this:

```
io.connect("http://yourdomain:8080/chat"); // with namespace
```

So a sample workflow would be:

- **nginx** listens on port 80
- **nodejs** listens on port 8080
- **socket.io** listens on port 8080 through nodejs app
- **nginx** proxies any requests on port 80 over to nodejs on 8080
- **socket.io** client connects directly to node/socket server on port 8080 and communicates directly without involvement of a reverse proxy

I can't get it working - is it not possible, or am I doing something wrong?

> EDIT:  This DOES actually work, my problem was sending MongoDB `_id` fields to the client.

I wrote a more detailed description [here](http://nathanstarner.com/post/20202138488/socket-io-and-nginx-workaround)

Comment: have you looked at the [`proxy_buffering`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering) option?

Comment: See my (unaccepted) answer to [an earlier question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749070/nginx-redirect-http-request-to-tcp/9749368#9749368

Comment: Thanks for the comments!  What I was trying to do was get around having to make any adjustments to nginx.  Actually the above code works, the problem was with mongoDB.  So you actually are able to specify a port in the socket.io connect and completely route it around nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I should be possible with NGINX 1.3 once it's released. Version 1.2 added support for HTTP/1.1 protocol which was essential missing piece.